# Wordpress: console errors from web sites I have linked to

Tags: wordpress, cors, content-security-policy

On this one page of my site, https://litchfieldmagazine.com/litchfield-county-design-resource-guide/

I have hundreds of console errors that are coming from sites I have linked to in the posts displayed on the page. Security errors, iframe warning, font warnings etc.

I know what to do if these were errors on **my site**, but why am I getting errors about content that is not even on my site, but is on someone else's that I have just hyperlinked to?

I have never seen anything like this before.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a new "Feature" of wordpress, if you add a full-qualified link in its own paragraph, it tries to "Embed" the link.  I assume this was to simplify embedding youtube videos and the like.

To fix it, I removed the `http://` from the links and made sure the link was part of another paragraph.  Problem went away.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer.  Please accept it in a couple of days for future readers.  - a different